# How to split whole sentence in column into a characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering how to split sentence into separated letters/characters. For example I have column with `（Merged）George The Great, Boss of Cats.` . I would like to ask for help how to split this whole sentence into  letters. I know that longest sentence is having 198 digits and would like to have Everything separated. Final output :
`( M e r g e d )  G e o r g e T h e  G r e a t ,  B o s s  o f  C a t s .` Then I would try to compare it(every single digit versus non latin character).. Could you please help me in that tricky case ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare it(every single digit versus non latin character)"? What database are you using?

Comment: I need to iterate through whole sentence and for example  keep distinct  G and S digits it is doable ? I'm working on Microsoft Database

Comment: Where will you keep these distinct characters, what will you do with them?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Management SQL Studio 2018. These characters will be final output, after receiving it I will just copy it to Excel :)

Comment: FWIW, their meant the MS "SQL Server" `RDBMS` version, not the one of the MS "Management Studio"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that experienced one. Where I can find that information ?

Comment: There is no such thing as SQL Server Management Studio 2018 (it's also not called Microsoft Management SQL Studio), @KND894GJ . though I asked for the version of SQL Server, *not* the IDE like environment you are using; the latest version of SSMS (SSMS 18) supports SQL Server 2008-2019 for example, which really doesn't help us understand what version you are using. You can get the version of SQL Server you are using by getting the value of `@@VERSION`.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Nobody understands what you are trying to do here at all. But I suspect you want to look at substring. And then you probably want to look into using a tally table. I would be happy to help you with that but I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

With no response to the version of SQL Server you are using, I'm going to *assume* you are using a supported version (SQL Server 2017+); this means you have access to `STRING_AGG`.

It looks like you want to a effectively put a space between each non-space character, and "double up" any spaces in there (I assume that `g e T h` should actually be `g e  T h`).

You can split the string into individual characters using a tally. I'm going to use function here, as it's more reusable. Then you can `SUBSTRING` to get the individual characters, and finally `STRING_AGG` to reaggregate the characters. Also note that if the value is a whitespace, I make it a zero length string, which results in a single space:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Tally] (@LastNumber int, @Zero bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @Zero = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (@LastNumber)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7) --Up to 10,000,000 rows
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally T;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            YourColumn nvarchar(100));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (YourColumn)
VALUES(N'（Merged）George The Great, Boss of Cats.');
GO

SELECT STRING_AGG(IIF(V.C = ' ','',V.C),' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.Tally(LEN(YT.YourColumn),1) T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(YT.YourColumn,T.I,1)))V(C)
GROUP BY YT.ID;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d47c68a2f25b9cb265fd07df61b28867)